# Metapost compiler freezes when I add labels

Tags: metapost

I installed texlive-metapost in Linux Mint (similar to Ubuntu), and each time I compile a MetaPost figure which contains a label, the compiler finishes the job, but the picture is not saved as ps, i.e. I cannot open it. I am thinking that maybe mpost does not compile latex formulas, but the compiler still doesn't give a result even when the formulas do not contain Latex. What is the problem, and what can I do?

I noticed that in the online live previewer which can be found [here](http://www.tlhiv.org/mppreview/) the mp file compiles with no problems. Is there a similar compiler for MetaPost, which can be installed (for which you write the code in the left side and in the right side you get the preview, like Gummi?)?

Thank you.

Comment: It would be useful if you showed an example that fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MetaPost will not typeset the labels, that task is handed over to TeX. Make sure, you have TeX set up in your metapost file. Here's a simple example that typesets the labels with LaTeX and prints "Hello World!". Save the file as `file.mp` and run it through MetaPost.

```
prologues:=3;
verbatimtex
%&latex
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
etex

beginfig (1)
        label(btex Hello World! etex, origin);
endfig;
bye
```

Here's an example that typesets the labels with ConTeXt (save the file as `file.tex` and run `context file`).

```
\starttext
    \startMPpage
        label(textext("Hello World!"), origin);
    \stopMPpage
\stoptext
```

This should get you started.

Comment: Do you know why those lines are needed? For example, first I added everything but the line prologues:=3 and the figure did not compile. verbatimtex is a tex distribution? Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @BeniBogosel: For information about `verbatimtex` see the [MetaPost man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mpost), for ConTeXt related stuff see the [Mpgraphic wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Mpgraphic) and for the `prologues` have a look at chapter 8.1 in the [MetaPost manual](http://tug.org/docs/metapost/mpman.pdf).